# Why can't I use Options inside of a slick query

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

In order to save me having to create so many methods, I tried passing in Option's into my method and then checking if the Option is defined, if so, then apply the filter.

```
def getUsers(locationId: Option[Int], companyId: Int, salary: Option[Int]): List[User] = {
  val query = for {
    u <- users if u.companyId === companyId && (locationId.isDefined && u.locationId === locationId.get) && (salary.isDefined && u.salary >= salary.get)

  }
  query.list()
}
```

I am getting errors saying:

```
polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;

IntelliJ errors are expected Boolean actual Column[Boolean].
```

Is this type of clause just not possible in a slick query or I'm just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I can't tell you why but this compiles for me:

```
def getUsers(locationId: Option[Int], companyId: Int, salary: Option[Int]): List[User] = {
  val query = for {
    u <- users if u.companyId === companyId && locationId.isDefined && u.locationId === locationId.get && salary.isDefined && u.salary >= salary.get
  } yield(u)
  query.list()
}
```

Note that there are no parenthesis and that you have to `yield` something otherwise the return type for `query` would be `Unit`.

Comment: it does at a 'true' to my query i.e where (... ... and true)

Comment: Uhm to me compiles without errors, have you removed the parenthesis around the conditions? E.g. instead of `if true && (id === thatId)` should be `if true && id === thatId`. In the end the `if` in the for comprehension desugarize to a lazy variant of `filter`, namely `withFilter` and it should compile if you have a `true` inside, I just tried id.

Comment: yes it compiles fine I'm just saying it inserts a ```true``` into the sql query.

Comment: I see, I misread your comment. To be honest I had doubt that this could work but I couldn't run an actual query. Probably the full filter condition is translated to SQL from slick where it doesn't make sense (but it does in Scala). I'm curious about how Slick will translate a `None` and the successive condition in this situation. You could split the query in small pieces, e.g. do the first filter, then if isDefined is true apply the second and so on, but this will be verbose and miss the point of for comprehensions.This is as far as I can go, hopefully somebody else will give a better answer.

Comment: Slick translates the None as SQL NULL including SQLs 3-valued-logic NULL propagation, so (None === a)  is None regardless of the value of a, even if a is None, the comparison result is still None, which SQL interprets as false. Same for &&. So basically if anything is None in the expression, the whole expression will be None, so the filter expression will be treated as false and the query result will be empty.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, don't see any issue here, just use filter (or withFilter) and map over the options.

```
def getUsers(locationId: Option[Int], companyId: Int, salary: Option[Int]): List[User] = (for {
  u <- users filter(u=>
    if (u.companyId === companyId.bind) && 
    (locationId.map(_.bind === u.locationId).getOrElse(true)) && 
    (salary.map(_.bind <= u.salary).getOrElse(true))
  )
} yield u).list()
```

Using filter allows you to drop down to Scala for the map or true fallback expressions. If you start with `u < users if...` then there's no way to use Scala conditionals. The `bind` calls just escape potential malicious input (i.e. if params are coming from outside the application).

Answer (score 1):

#### Why it doesn't work

As cvot has noted [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514913/why-cant-i-use-options-inside-of-a-slick-query#comment37969976_24515772), the reason this doesn't work is because:

> Slick translates the None as SQL NULL including SQLs 3-valued-logic NULL propagation, so (None === a) is None regardless of the value of a ... basically if anything is None in the expression, the whole expression will be None, so the filter expression will be treated as false and the query result will be empty.

That said, there is a way to get the same *behavior* you want (filtering only if an optional value is provided).

#### A way to arrive at the desired behavior

The key thing to note is that for comprehensions get compiled down by Scala to a combination of `map` / `flatMap` / `withFilter` / `filter` calls.  Slick, if I understand it correctly, works with the resulting structure when it compiles the Scala comprehension into a SQL query.

This lets us build up a query in parts:

```
val baseQuery = for {
  u <- users if u.companyId === companyId
} yield u

val possiblyFilteredByLocation = if (locationId.isDefined) {
  baseQuery.withFilter(u => u.locationId === locationId.get
} else baseQuery

val possiblyFilteredBySalaryAndOrLocation = if (salary.isDefined) {
  possiblyFilteredByLocation.withFilter(u => u.salary >= salary.get)
} else possiblyFilteredByLocation

possiblyFilteredBySalaryAndOrLocation.list()
```

We can simplify this by using a `var` and `fold`:

```
var query = for {
  u <- users if u.companyId === companyId
} yield u
query = locationId.fold(query)(id => query.withFilter(u => u.locationId === id))
query = salary.fold(query)(salary => query.withFilter(u => u.salary >= salary))
query.list()
```

If we do this frequently, we can generalize this pattern of filtering on an `Option` into something like this:

```
// Untested, probably does not compile
implicit class ConditionalFilter(query: Query) {
  def ifPresent[T](value: Option[T], predicate: (Query, T) => Query) = {
    value.fold(query)(predicate(query, _))
  }
}
```

Then we can simplify our whole filter chain to:

```
query
  .ifPresent[Int](locationId, (q, id) => q.withFilter(u => u.locationId === id))
  .ifPresent[Int](salary, (q, s) => q.withFilter(u => u.salary >= s))
  .list()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution (with Slick 3.3.x):

```
def getUsers(locationId: Option[Int], companyId: Int, minSalary: Option[Int]) = 
  users.
    .filter(_.company === companyId)
    .filterOpt(locationId)(_.locationId === _)
    .filterOpt(minSalary)(_.salary >= _)
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the Slick query gets translated into SQL, which has no notion of the isDefined and get methods of the Option class. 
But you can fix this by calling the methods outside the query and passing the results (via the map function on the options).

The following code should fix it:

```
def getUsers(locationId: Option[Int], companyId: Int, salary: Option[Int]): List[User] = {
    val locationAndSalary = for {
        locId <- locationId;
        sal <- salary
    } yield (locId, sal)

    locationAndSalary.map(locAndSal => {
        val query = for {
            u <- users if u.companyId === companyId && u.locationId === locAndSal._1 && u.salary >= locAndSal._2)  
        } yield u
        query.list()
    }).getOrElse(List[User]()) //If the locationID or salary is None, return empty list.
}
```

The `locationAndSalary` may seem strange, but we are using for comprehensions to give use a value only when both `locationId` and `salary` has a value and storing the result in a tuple, with the locationId in the first position and salary at the second. The following links explains it: [Scala: for comprehensions with Options](http://java.dzone.com/articles/scala-comprehensions-options).

Edit: According to @Ende Neu answer the code compiles if you add the yield-statement, but I still think my solution is more the "Scala way".

Comment: Hi, but this isn't what I am after.  I want to ignore the locationId and salary where filters if they are None and just have companyId.  Your query is not the same thing as it will return List[User]() if they are None.